# Query Designer in SSMS as Default

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The Query designer used to be build in for visual studio. For version 2013 it has been removed. 
The only way to use it, is the SSMS, but this is kinda clupsy since you have to mark the SQL statement and have a new window popup. No direct exectution, etc.

Is there a way to use the query designer within SSMS as the default editor for scripting?
Or is there a tool out tehre, which is as powerfull as the designer used to be in VS<=2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **View Designer** for *SSMS* does the trick. In fact, this is the Query Designer using in VS2010.

Good Job MS :(